# De-puncturing in soft-decision Viterbi decoding using vitdec

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, telecommunication

I am implementing a communication system using Matlab, and I had previously done convolutional encoding with puncturing on a binary stream, using `convenc`. However, I checked the documentation for `vitdec` (Viterbi decoding), and this is what I found.

```matlab
decoded = vitdec(code,trellis,tblen,opmode,dectype)
decoded = vitdec(code,trellis,tblen,opmode,'soft',nsdec)
decoded = ... vitdec(code,trellis,tblen,opmode,dectype,puncpat)
decoded = ... vitdec(code,trellis,tblen,opmode,dectype,puncpat,eraspat)
decoded = ... vitdec(...,'cont',...,initmetric,initstates,initinputs) 
[decoded,finalmetric,finalstates,finalinputs] = ... vitdec(...,'cont',...)
```

For the second function definition (with soft decoding), there is no parameter for the puncture pattern vector. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

The following function is not listed in the documentation but I tried it and it works:

```
decoded = vitdec(code,trellis,tblen,opmode,'soft',nsdec,puncpat)
```

Make sure you understand that now the elements in the `code` variable need to be between `0` and `2^nsdec-1`, not `0` or `1` like with hard decision mode.

Answer (score 0):

Per MATLAB Documentation (https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/vitdec.html)

`decoded = ... vitdec(code,trellis,tblen,opmode,dectype,puncpat)`

dectype indicates the type of decision that the decoder makes, and influences the type of data the decoder expects in code.

One of the choices for dectype is "soft". Seems like you just put in the puncture pattern in puncpat exactly the same as you did for convenc.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this command assuming that `code1` is your code:

```
% trellis = poly2trellis(L, [n1 n2]); n1 and n2 is polynome order
% tbln = 1
c = vitdec(code1, trellis, tbln, 'trunc', 'hard')
```